# Missing MethodCompletedEventHandler after consuming web service in .NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, wpf, .net-core

I'm working on an application which has web service and I'm consuming the web service from a WPF application as well as .NET Core application, but in WPF application the `reference.cs` file has events as shown here:

```
/// <remarks/>
public event GenerateReportCompletedEventHandler GenerateReportCompleted;
    
/// <remarks/>
public event DownloadReportsCompletedEventHandler DownloadReportsCompleted;
```

but whereas in my .NET Core application I didnt find such events - instead it has `async` methods as shown:

```
///<remarks/>
public System.Threading.Tasks.Task<NibrsReportingService.ReportPath>         GenerateReportAsync(NibrsReportingService.ReportCriteria criteria, string userToken)
{
    return base.Channel.GenerateReportAsync(criteria, userToken);
}
    
public System.Threading.Tasks.Task<NibrsReportingService.ReportFiles[]> DownloadReportsAsync(string processId, string userToken)
{
    return base.Channel.DownloadReportsAsync(processId, userToken);
}
```

I need the event handlers in my .NET Core reference as well - is there a way to get those event in my .NET Core reference as well?

Or can I achieve the functionality similar to this:

```
service.GenerateReportCompleted += NVS_SubmissionCompleted;
```

with those async events?

Comment: Those events are part of **WPF** - so if you're using WPF on .NET Core, you should have those as well - any other type of application won't have those events per se